# How to make hoverover table NOT effect other divs?

Tags: html, css, hover, css-tables

This is a three-part question:

1. How can I make a hover-over div (that is in a page-wrap) NOT effect other divs that are within the div? When hovered, everything else slides down.
2. How can I make it so that everything outside the button will not trigger the hover-over effect?
3. How can I remove the border around the texts?

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kenhimself/prven5sy/5/).

**HTML:**

```
<div class="page">

    <div class="text"> 
        <span class="title">Hover Here</span>
        <span class="info">This text should hover over the images, not effect the bottom images <br/>text <br/>text <br/>text <br/>text <br/>text <br/>text <br/>text <br/>text <br/>text
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img... />
        <img... />
        <img... />
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
    html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
body {
    font-family: helvetica;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 26px;
}
div.page {
    width:80%;
    max-width:960px;
    height:100%;
    background: #C2DAB6;
    margin:0 auto;
}
div.text span.title {
    display:inline;
}
div.text:hover span.title {
    display:none;
}
div.text span.info {
    display:none;
}
div.text:hover span.info {
    display:inline;
}
.image img {
    width: 60%;
    height: auto;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following code
If you want to remove border of text class then make

```
<table border="0">


 .text{
        position: absolute;
    background: #fff;
        z-index: 9999;
    }
    .image{
        position:relative;
    top:20px;
    }
```

You can check on fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/nikkirs/prven5sy/6/

Comment: Bingo! Thank you nikita. I've marked this answer correct.

Comment: Hi Nikita, another question. How can I get the title and info text to fadeIn and fadeOut when hovering? I tried everything but it doesn't seem like display is incompatible with CSS transitions...

Comment: Thanks for the link! I managed to get the fadein/ fadeout effect going, but the problem if the person hovers their mouse on the top column, it'll still trigger the hover-over effect. any way I can get the hover-over effect to trigger ONLY if the person hovers over the title text? http://jsfiddle.net/kenhimself/nup3c5w0/3/